# how to add column to manage customers grid and it should work as filter?

Tags: customer, newsletter, grid, customer-grid, join-table

I want to add news letter subscribed or not as column.
but I dont have idea from which table i have to join.
can you any one help me on this?

```
class Gumbrands_Customergrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid{
    /**
     * override the _prepareCollection to add an other attribute to the grid
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection(){
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer, use the line below
            ->addAttributeToSelect('news_letter')
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer address, comment the line above and use the one below
            //->joinAttribute('mobile', 'customer_address/mobile', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        //code from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()
        //since calling parent::_prepareCollection will render the code above useless
        //and you cannot call in php parent::parent::_prepareCollection()
        if ($this->getCollection()) {

            $this->_preparePage();

            $columnId = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort);
            $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir);
            $filter   = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);

            if (is_null($filter)) {
                $filter = $this->_defaultFilter;
            }

            if (is_string($filter)) {
                $data = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
                $this->_setFilterValues($data);
            }
            else if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
            }
            else if(0 !== sizeof($this->_defaultFilter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($this->_defaultFilter);
            }

            if (isset($this->_columns[$columnId]) && $this->_columns[$columnId]->getIndex()) {
                $dir = (strtolower($dir)=='desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                $this->_columns[$columnId]->setDir($dir);
                $this->_setCollectionOrder($this->_columns[$columnId]);
            }

            if (!$this->_isExport) {
                $this->getCollection()->load();
                $this->_afterLoadCollection();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * override the _prepareColumns method to add a new column after the 'email' column
     * if you want the new column on a different position just change the 3rd parameter
     * of the addColumnAfter method to the id of your desired column
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns(){
        $this->addColumnAfter('news_letter', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Mobile'),
            'index'     => 'mobile'
        ),'email');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046836/magento-add-column-to-customer-grid

Comment: i want syntax of join newsletter_subscriber

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  /**
>  * Preparing customer collection
>  */
> public function setCollection($collection)
> {
>   
>    
>    
>     $collection->addAttributeToSelect('newsletter_subscribed');
>     parent::setCollection($collection);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Adding columns to customer grid
>  */
> protected function _prepareColumns()
> {
>
>     parent::_prepareColumns();
>
>     $this->addColumnAfter('newsletter_subscribed', array(
>         'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Newsletter Subscribed'),
>         'index' => 'origin',
>         'type' => 'text',
>         'width' => '100px',
>             ), 'entity_id');
>     return parent::_prepareColumns();
> }
> ```

you can join newsletter_subscriber

Comment: can u give syntax for joinnewsletter_subscriber table